# How to clear input value on submit, while also adding the value to a span area?

Tags: javascript, html

For some reason I can only add the input value, but when I try adding a `.reset()` or setting `value=''` the former function doesn't work. How do I make both happen?

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function changeThis(){

      var formInput = document.getElementById('theInput').value;
      document.getElementById('newText').innerHTML = document.getElementById('newText').innerHTML + " " + formInput;
      document.getElementById('theInput').placeholder = "Next";
      formInput.reset(); // this is where the problem starts
      return false; // someone recommended to do this... Didn't work

}
</script>

<span id='newText'></span>
<form>
     <input type='text' id='theInput' placeholder='Continue Again' keyfilter="A-Za-z" maxlength=6/>
     <input type='button' id="theSubmit" onclick='changeThis()' value='Add'/>
     <input type='button' value= "Refresh" onclick="history.go(0)"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `formInput` variable copies the value from the input, It does not maintain a reference to the input it copied it from. It is just text.

Also, `reset()` is for `<form>` elements, not inputs.

I'd change `formInput` to reference the input itself, and then add `.value` to all the other places you have it (including `formInput.value = ""` instead of `formInput.reset()`). That would look like this:

```
function changeThis(){
      var formInput = document.getElementById('theInput');
      document.getElementById('newText').innerHTML = document.getElementById('newText').innerHTML + " " + formInput.value;
      document.getElementById('theInput').placeholder = "Next";
      formInput.value = ""; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the reset function on the form, not the input:

```
<form id="someid">

var someid = document.getElementById('someid');
someid.reset();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   var formInput = document.getElementById('theInput').value;
   ... some more code
    formInput.reset();
```

`formInput` is a string , it doesn't have any `reset()` method.

to reset the form call `reset()` on form.

```
var form= document.querySelector('form');
form.reset();
```

here's  a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/8cxtszyb/1/

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function changeThis(){

      var txtInput = document.getElementById('theInput').value;
      document.getElementById('newText').innerHTML += " " + txtInput;
      document.getElementById('theInput').placeholder = "Next";
      document.getElementById("fInput").reset(); // Call reset on Form object
      return false;

}
</script>

<span id='newText'></span>
<form id="fInput">
     <input type='text' id='theInput' placeholder='Continue Again' keyfilter="A-Za-z" maxlength=6/>
     <input type='button' id="theSubmit" onclick='changeThis()' value='Add'/>
     <input type='button' value= "Refresh" onclick="history.go(0)"/>
</form>
```

Based on [this page from W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_form.asp), it appears that you need to call `.reset()` on the form itself, rather than the `input` element inside of it (`theInput`).

Answer (score 0):

friend i have tried something, have 
[a look](https://jsfiddle.net/ujdw2uap/)!

onsubmit function goes like this

```
function submitForm(){
     var a=document.getElementById('input').value;
     document.getElementById('target').innerHTML += " " + a;
     document.getElementById('input').value="";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

also works:

```
<span id='newText'></span>
<form>
     <input type='text' id='theInput' placeholder='Continue Again' keyfilter="A-Za-z" maxlength=6/>
     <input type='button' id="theSubmit" onclick='changeThis()' value='Add'/>
     <input type='button' value= "Refresh" onclick="history.go(0)"/>
     <input type='reset' id="reset" value= "Reset" style="display:none;"/>
</form>

function changeThis(){

      var formInput = document.getElementById('theInput').value;
      document.getElementById('newText').innerHTML = document.getElementById('newText').innerHTML + " " + formInput;
      document.getElementById('reset').click();
      document.getElementById('theInput').placeholder = "Next";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a jsfiddle that works: https://jsfiddle.net/bap8af6a/
(I had to move the onclick assignment under the function because in the HTML section it hadn't been initiated yet.)

```
function changeThis(){

  var formInput = document.getElementById('theInput').value;
  document.getElementById('newText').innerHTML = document.getElementById('newText').innerHTML + " " + formInput;
  document.getElementById('theInput').placeholder = "Next";
  //document.getElementById('theInput').value = ''; // one way
  document.getElementById('theForm').reset(); // or the other
  //return false; // used in form to prevent default behavior
}
```

So, there are two ways to do this based on your code. (Probably more)
You can set the value of the input or you can reset the form. You can't reset the value of the input. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset

If you were using this form like a real form with an action and method, then the return false would be useful to prevent the default behavior of an input of type 'submit'. (Default behavior being to submit the form to your backend.) However, you don't have any of those things, so it's kind of useless.